# Convert array of rows into array of strings in pyspark

Tags: python-2.7, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with 2 columns and I got below array by doing **df.collect()**.

```
array = [Row(name=u'Alice', age=10), Row(name=u'Bob', age=15)]
```

Now I want to get an output array like below.

```
new_array = ['Alice', 'Bob']
```

Could anyone please let me know how to extract above output using pyspark. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# Creating the base dataframe.
values = [('Alice',10),('Bob',15)]
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(values,['name','age'])
df.show()
    +-----+---+
    | name|age|
    +-----+---+
    |Alice| 10|
    |  Bob| 15|
    +-----+---+

df.collect()
    [Row(name='Alice', age=10), Row(name='Bob', age=15)]

# Use list comprehensions to create a list.
new_list = [row.name for row in df.collect()]
print(new_list)
    ['Alice', 'Bob']
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When I do df.collect() I'm getting array like [Row(name=u'Alice', age=10), Row(name=u'Bob', age=15)]. So when used row.name I'm getting u['Alice', u'Bob'] instead of ['Alice', 'Bob']

Comment: It's the same thing. Don't worry, all good. `u` does not have any effect on data- it is just an explicit representation of unicode object (not byte array).

Comment: Oh ok. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I see two columns name and age in the df. Now, you want only the `name` column to be displayed.

You can select it like:

```
df.select("name").show()
```

This will show you only the names.

Tip: Also, you `df.show()` instead of `df.collect()`. That will show you in tabular form instead of row(...)